# Deformation theorem and Tristan Needham's proof of Cauchy's formula

Tags: complex-analysis

In pg 428 of Visual Complex Analysis, a proof of Cauchy's formula is being done and I am having the step of evaluating :

$$ \oint \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \frac{dz}{2\pi i} = <f>_{C_r}$$

My issue is in the remark he mentions of identifying the integral on left as the average of function over circle

> Now shrink the cirlce $C_r$ towards its centre a, as illustrated in [1a]. Even if f is merely continuous (rather than analytic), $f(C_r)$ will shrink to $f(a)$ as indicated in $[1b]$... contin

How is it possible that we can apply the deform the curve if the function is only continuous? To my understanding integrals are same under deformation theorem only if the function is analytic while it is being deformed into the new region. Is there some other theorem which is being applied?

Comment: A formatting tip: Angle brackets $\langle \cdots \rangle$ are `\langle` and `\rangle`, as opposed to the less-than and greater-than signs `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the statement being made. What Needham is saying is that $f$ being analytic implies that for a "nice loop" $L$ and any radius $r>0$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz \tag{Cauchy's theorem}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{f(a+re^{it})}{re^{it}}ire^{it}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{it})\,dt\\
&=\text{average of $f$ over $C_r$}
\end{align}
Since this is true for all $r>0$, we can now take limits to deduce
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz&=
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\left(\text{average of $f$ on $C_r$}\right)
\end{align}
Clearly, the LHS doesn't even depend on $r$, so we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L\frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz&=
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\left(\text{average of $f$ on $C_r$}\right)
\end{align}
Finally, he is saying that $f$ analytic implies in particular $f$ is continuous, and that continuity of $f$ (at $a$) implies the last limit is equal to $f(a)$.

Comment: Oh right, so he is not saying "this proof can work even for continuous functions" but rather saying, we just need continuity for taking the limit operation in the final step

Comment: @Buraian yes exactly. And if you want the details: Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By continuity of $f$ at $a$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $|z-a|<\delta$ then $|f(z)-f(a)|<\epsilon$. So, for any $0<r<\delta$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(a+re^{it})\,dt-f(a)\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}[f(a+re^{it})-f(a)]\,dt\right|\\
&\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(a+re^{it})-f(a)|\,dt\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\epsilon\,dt\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align}Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this shows from definition $f(a)$ is the limit of the averages.

Comment: My English is too bad 

Answer (score 3):

Analyticity is used to say that the integral doesn't depend on $r$. If $f$ is not analytic but merely continuous, then the average can depend on $r$, but it still approaches $f(a)$ as $r\to0$.  When $r$ is near $0$, all the values of $f$ on the circle $C_r$ are close to $f(a)$, and therefore so is their average.

Comment: I feel you didn't understand me. The issue I am asking is how do we know that the integral is same for some specific value of r and r in the limit?

Comment: @Buraian We don't know that, and Needham didn't say that.  As I said, if $f$ is merely continuous, not analytic, then we know that  the average approaches $f(a)$ as $r\to0$, but not that it equals $f(a)$ for any particular $r$.

Comment: If you do the proof, you will see why the claim is true. Parameterize the integral of $f$ on the curves and estimate the values of the integral.

Comment: @AndreasBlass in the end of proof he says the proof of cauchy formula is done since as limit $r->0$ value of the integral gives f(a) that must be same value of integral for the original value of radius

Comment: @Buraian Sure; the theorem is about analytic functions. The only thing Needham claims about continuous **non-analytic** functions is that the integral approaches $f(a)$ as $r\to0$. In other words, the phrase "Even if $f$ is merely continuous" refers to the **one** sentence in which it occurs, not to the whole proof or to the theorem.

Comment: Right. Thank you, I misunderstood what he was referring to when he said that.